# Get text from clipboard ON CLICK in firefox and safari with Javascript

Tags: javascript, clipboard

I am looking for a way to paste text from clipboard by clicking button with Javascript in Firefox and Safari.

I wrote this code for that.

```
function paste() {
    let pasteArea = document.querySelector("textarea");
    pasteArea.value = "";
    navigator.clipboard.readText().then((text) => {
        pasteArea.value = text;
    });
},
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", paste);
```

Chrome works with it but not for safari and firefox, and it gives an error since browsers do not support it;

```
Firefox; TypeError: navigator.clipboard.read is not a function
Safari; TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigator.clipboard.readText')
```

I also tried

```
document.execCommand('paste', false, null);
```

but did not work for either of them because of browser support.
I also tried

```
 event.clipboardData.getData("text/plain");
```

but did not work with click event but it worked with paste event which I do not want.

I want to avoid to use Flush, and want to paste text with CLICK event. Is it possible?